# Find lines between two patterns and append lines with pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, python, perl

We have the following file where a bunch of records (million records) of interest are between the start and end of patterns. The start pattern always start with an A and the end pattern always starts with a Z.

```
Apattern1   somethinghere    #start of pattern always starts with A
Line-of-data-here-aaa
Line-of-data-here-xxxxx
Zpattern1  #end of pattern always starts with Z
ApatternX   somethinghere    #Repeat: start of pattern always starts with A
Line-of-data-here-bbbb
Line-of-data-here-yyyy
Line-of-data-here-nnnnn
ZpatternX
```

We Want to transform the data by appending the start pattern (entire line) to the lines within the pattern. We want to remove the end pattern. We want to use sed and/or awk to append the lines that start the pattern (starts with A) to the lines within the pattern (starts with L) and get rid of the end of the pattern (always starts with Z)So the data file would look like this:

```
Apattern1   somethinghere  Line-of-data-here-aaa
Apattern1   somethinghere   Line-of-data-here-xxxxx
ApatternX   somethinghere   Line-of-data-here-bbbb
ApatternX   somethinghere  Line-of-data-here-yyyy
ApatternX   somethinghere  Line-of-data-here-nnnnn
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you are asking for this:

```
sed -E '/^A/h;/^[AZ]/d;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' yourfile
```

So lines starting with `A` are copied to the hold space (`/^A/h`),
then lines starting with either `A` or `Z` are deleted as we don't want to print them (`/^[AZ]/d`). For all other lines the hold space with the `A` line gets appended (`G`), both parts get exchanged separated by a whitespace instead of a newline (`s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/`)

*(A little easier with an `sed` expansion I did for myself: `\h` in the replacement gets expanded to the contents of the hold buffer:*

```
sed -E '/^A/h;/^[AZ]/d;G;s/^/\h /' yourfile
```

*If I meet more questions like this, I'll do a merge request for it.)*

Comment: I think you got it. Thank you ...Thank you....Thank you.....I really appreciate it. Can I ask you what would you recommend as a study material for sed and or awk.

Comment: I've seen some, but they are huge and I'm not sure whether this is a good idea to spend hours on theoretically learning such a language. Long ago, I started using `sed` with some basics like addressing, `s` and `d` command and not much more. Each time I met a more complex task I looked in the `man` page what could help me do it, so I learned something new each time. You might give [this tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) a try, but I recommend not reading all. Better learn by doing. And consider setting a mark that the question has been answered.

Comment: The test data worked but the actual data did not work. I wonder what am I missing 

Actual file:
P36215ARK

L12929010235171953162F  09570          752NN03800005002 1DE      N 201705

T36215ARK0

P36215BYU

L13042310235630823162V2 08723          721NN          1 1AR      N 201705

T36215BYU



I ran this:
sed -E '/^P/h;/^[PT]/d;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' filename
and got this (not appending the lines starting with P)


L12929010235171953162F  09570          752NN03800005002 1DE      N 201705


L13042310235630823162V2 08723          721NN          1 1AR      N 201705

Comment: So when the pattern is changed from A to P and T to Z it did not work.

Comment: Please place that actual file in the question (edit question and paste with 4 spaces in front of each line), so it becomes readable

Comment: P36215ARK    
L12929010235171953162F  09570          752NN03800005002 1DE      N 201705
T36215ARK0    
P36215BYU      
L13042310235630823162V2 08723          721NN          1 1AR      N 201705
T36215BYU

Comment: Ok I am adding 4 spaces at the end of each line. I am still not able to paste the data spaced out. I am going to try again with help ....

Comment: P36202AAD9000004MSF19920701    201705    
L00000410232086241798F1 19920601202205010745000002900000           0000103539236030006000    09566              N03800005001 1MO      N 201705    
T36202AAD9000004MSF19920701    2017050000001

Comment: You misunderstood me: **Edit your question** and paste the actual file there. When pasting it, insert four spaces **at the beginning** of each line, as you see it with your example that I edited for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   /^A/,/^Z/!d
   //{h;d;}
   G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\t\1/
' yourfile
```

---

## Results:

```
Apattern1   somethinghere       Line-of-data-here-aaa
Apattern1   somethinghere       Line-of-data-here-xxxxx
ApatternX   somethinghere       Line-of-data-here-bbbb
ApatternX   somethinghere       Line-of-data-here-yyyy
ApatternX   somethinghere       Line-of-data-here-nnnnn
```

---

## Explanation

- Select the right range by rejecting the incorrect range: '/^A/,/^Z/!d'
- Store the range boundaries in te hold space.
- Range internals, append hold into current line and flip + change \n to tab.

Comment: Hi, Actual data is here and the first column is being chopped off.                                                                                                               P36215ARK    
L12929010235171953162F 09570 752NN03800005002 1DE N 201705
T36215ARK0    
P36215BYU      
L13042310235630823162V2 08723 721NN   1 1AR N 201705
T36215BYU

Comment: I am sorry but how do I paste the data so the lines are not merged.

Comment: @N.E Why don't you upload your data file on the https://pastebin.com website ?

Comment: @N.E So what you are saying is that insead of the `A` and `Z` as the markers of the beginning/end of data ranges you have `P` and `T`. Is that correct? Why didn't you provide the original data to begin with. It would been so much better for everybody concerned.

Comment: I was trying to simplify it. I did not expect that there would be a big difference for switching from A to P ....(is it?)

Comment: So the actual data is this (pattern repeats with records starting with L could be 1 or many)
P36202AAD9000004MSF19920701    201705    
L00000410232086241798F1 19920601202205010745000002900000           0000103539236030006000    09566              N03800005001 1MO      N 201705      
T36202AAD9000004MSF19920701    2017050000001

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure how to paste this with new lines characters so you can see the records as they actually appear. There are 3 records pasted above, the first starts with P and the middle with L and the last with T.

Comment: @N.E It would be much better to simply upload your inputs/expected outputs on the https://pastebin.com website.